# Easiest way to share work between backend and front end

Tags: python, django, installation

Hey everyone, 
I am expanding my team and I have recently added an additional front end engineer on my site. I am currently using django to run my site but my site is using a lot of plugins, namely: django-celery, django-mailer, django-notification, and django-socialregistration.

Let me describe my situation:

1. He is using Mac OS X, and I have no experience in installing stuff on mac os X or configuration on that platform
2. I believe that getting my backend to run on his computer might be somewhat troublesome, i.e. I have to install a bunch of plugins (which are not available on pip or easy_install as they are the latest version) and I have also made heavy modification to django-socialregistration which I am currently using by symlinking to the modified code in my repos in my python path
3. I tried to look into solutions like pip and easy_install but I have not been able to get them to install code from github

I think the easiest way is to get my backend working on his computer and then he just commiting to the repos. Any ideas how I can make this easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, free option, is to use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).  I would recommend installing the same OS on it as your production server.  Then, he's developing in the same environment as the live site, and can just check into the repo the same as you.  Hey, you may want to do the same on your end--then both of your environments are the same and also the same as the live site.

Comment: Right, this is the simplest solution, then you take care of installing stuff in his VM, or just use "pip freeze" > requirements.txt - Remember to use "bridge mode" for the Virtualbox IP, so the VM is on the same subnet as his Mac, and you can even access it through NAT traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Get him to set up a virtual machine on his Mac, using VMWare Fusion or Parallels, running the same operating system that you currently use for your back end.  If he prefers developing using Mac tools he can do still that by sharing his local changes to the virtual machine via a shared directory.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, if that's possible, would be to set up a testing/development environment on a machine with an OS you're familiar with, then install something like Dropbox on his local machine where he can develop the frontend code, and install Dropbox on that other environment with the backend components. Dropbox would sync his local changes to that testing environment for him to run the code on.

That way, he would be able to use that environment to test his code, you wouldn't need to set up a backend on his machine (or keep it up to date) and you'd still be getting the same functionality.

Again, if that's an option.